# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module first.ko: Invalid module format in WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I compiled the Linux kernel source code by following the instructions present at accepted answer [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594470/wsl-2-does-not-have-lib-modules/645131#645131).

While inserting the .ko file which was generated using the below make file and driver code I am getting the Invalid module format error. Any help on how to solve this error would be helpful, thank you.

**Driver Code**

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
static int hello_init(void)
{
 printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
 return 0;
}
static void hello_exit(void)
{
 printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

**Makefile:**

```
obj-m:=first.o
all:
    make -C $(shell pwd)/../WSL2-Linux-Kernel M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    make -C $(shell pwd)/../WSL2-Linux-Kernel M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

Note: I pasted the bzimage at location `C:\Users\Lenovo` and the .wslconfig is as below

```
[wsl2]
kernel=C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\bzimage
```

The wsl version present on the PC is version 2

Comment: Is the VM actually running the kernel you expected? Check `cat /proc/version` output (which has a bit more information than `uname -a`).

Comment: No the VM is not running the excepted kernel. After changing the kernel to the compiled kernel as motioned in step6 [here](https://gist.github.com/cerebrate/d40c89d3fa89594e1b1538b2ce9d2720#step-seven-install-your-new-kernel) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error is encountered because the code is compiled to .ko using the custom compiled kernel which is not the same version as the kernel used by WSL-Ubuntu

This error can be resolved by pasting the custom compiled kernel's bzimage at `C:\Windows\System32\lxss\tools` and rename it as kernel.

By doing the above step WSL uses the custom compiled kernel instead of default Microsoft kernel.

For more information refer this [link](https://gist.github.com/cerebrate/d40c89d3fa89594e1b1538b2ce9d2720)